# fileter an arraylist of objects with respect to its fields in java?

Tags: java, sorting, filter

Suppose I have an arrray list of objects like the following:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "msg": "Teachers Classes",
    "data": [
        {
            "class_id": "2",
            "class": "3",
            "section": "A",
            "subject": "English"
        },
        {
            "class_id": "1",
            "class": "2",
            "section": "A",
            "subject": "Math"
        },
        {
            "class_id": "1",
            "class": "2",
            "section": "A",
            "subject": "Science"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, I want to filter the above arraylist based on value of two of its (class and section) fields(if they are similar), so as the resultant is somewhat as:

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "response_code": 200,
    "msg": "Teachers Classes",
    "data": [
        {
            "class_id": "2",
            "class": "3",
            "section": "A",
            "subject": "English"
        },
        {
            "class_id": "1",
            "class": "2",
            "section": "A",
            "subject": "Math, Science"
        }

    ]
}
```

Comment: And? What is the question here? What have you tried so far? What didn't work for you?

Comment: You might have better luck in getting answers if you describe what you have done so far, post some code, and ask a more specific question if the code does not behave as you expect. As it stands, it looks like you have not made any effort to do this yourself.